# How to iterate multiple json data in jquery response

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-arrays

[image]I am getting multiple data from my JSON response like below.

```
WellNames   […]
0   {…}
id  56
well_name   AL HALL
api 34005205550000
1   {…}
id  498
well_name   BONTRAGER
api 34005233850000
2   {…}
id  499
well_name   BONTRAGER
api 34005233860000
```

I just want to iterate all data and append in select box having id result

i tried below code but getting undefined value in select tags.Please help me to display this values in my select tag.

Below is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#clientname").on('change', function() { 
         ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
         url: '<?= Router::url(['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'getWelldetails']) ?>',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {clientId: $("#clientname").val()},   
             dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                $(response).each(function () {
                    $("<option value='" + response['id'] + "'>" + response['well_name'] + "</option>").appendTo('#result');
                });              
            },
            error: function(response) {         
            }
        });     

 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Did you try dropping a `console.log(response)` to see exactly what you receive ? Is it a String? An Array?

Comment: yes i tried and i pasted my output on wall

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the log in the console?

Comment: i did..please see the attached screenshot

Comment: Try changing `$(response).each` to `$(response.WellNames).each` and using `this` instead of `response` in the loop.

Comment: still getting undefined data

Comment: You are using the response to show data, which is wrong. Use value param $(response.welnames).each(function (i, value){} and use value['id'], etc... in your option

Comment: Thanks Albeis and thank you @Zenoo

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the `WellNames` property of your result, not on your result itself.

Also, you're not using jQuery `each` properly. Either use `$.each` or use a `for` loop:

```
for(let item of response.WellNames) {
    $("<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.well_name + "</option>").appendTo('#result');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its done from below changes which i forgot to write

```
$(response.WellNames).each(function (i,value) {
                    $("<option value='" + value['id'] + "'>" + value['well_name'] + " - " + value['api'] + "</option>").appendTo('#result');
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`You need iterate on *WellNames* property of your response.`

- Use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) so that you don't iterate on undefined property.
- I will not suggest to add elements directly to control in a loop. So create an array containing html of  and then add it to the control.

  `var arrHtml = [];
  for (var item of response.WellNames) {
     if (response.WellNames.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      arrHtml.push("<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.well_name + "</option>");
     }
  }
  $('#result').innerHtml = arrHtml.join();`